# Working using trig identity

Tags: trigonometry

Hi so I have this equation

$$\frac{1-e^2}{1+e\cos(\theta -\theta_{0})} = 1-e\cos\eta$$

and using the identity

$$\cos\theta = \frac{1-\tan^2 \frac\theta2}{1+\tan^2 \frac\theta2}$$

this becomes

$$\sqrt{1-e} \tan\left(\frac{\theta - \theta_{0}}2\right) = \sqrt{1+e} \tan\frac\eta2.$$

However, I'm unsure about the steps in between. Can someone help me out please?

Comment: @BarryCipra apologies, supposed to be a + on the bottom. edited it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $u=\tan((\theta-\theta_0)/2)$ and $v=\tan(\eta/2)$ for simplicity.

The left hand side becomes
$$
\frac{1-e^2}{1+e\dfrac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}}
=\frac{(1-e^2)(1+u^2)}{(1+e)+(1-e)u^2}
$$
The right hand side becomes
$$
1-e\frac{1-v^2}{1+v^2}=\frac{(1-e)+(1+e)v^2}{1+v^2}
$$
It's better to set $M=1-e$ and $P=1+e$, so we get a simpler identity
$$
\frac{MP(1+u^2)}{P+Mu^2}=\frac{M+Pv^2}{1+v^2}
$$
that can be rearranged to
$$
MP+MPv^2+MP(1+v^2)u^2=MP+P^2v^2+M^2u^2+MPu^2v^2
$$
Pull all terms with $u^2$ on the left hand side
$$
(MP+MPv^2-M^2-MPv^2)u^2=P^2v^2-MPv^2
$$
that simplifies to
$$
M(P-M)u^2=P(P-M)v^2
$$
Assuming $P-M=1+e-1+e=2e\ne0$, this becomes
$$
(1-e)\tan^2\frac{\theta-\theta_0}{2}=(1+e)\tan^2\frac{\eta}{2}
$$

Comment: Beat me to it, so +1.